# Have Markdown Update In Single Input

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, vuejs2

I've created a Markdown editor using Vue much like all the [example](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/examples/)s I seem to find which have a separate input and preview area. Although this question has more to do with implementation than Vue. As such I'm not looking for answers that necessarily use it.

What I'd like to try and accomplish is a single space where the user both enters text and immediately see's the updated Html.

Basically I want to accomplish what [Evernote](https://evernote.com/) does.

One way I can see this being achievable is by hiding the actual textarea input and mocking the preview area to look like that's actually where the user is adding their text.

1. Is this what others would recommend or is there a better approach?
2. How easy/hard is it to fake an input area in this manner?

My reservation over this method is how to fake the text-cursor (caret) and also handle allowing a user to go back and edit text.

3. Do I use the `contenteditable` tag and then handle the difference between the preview input and the hidden input?
4. Am I not better off then just doing away with the hidden input altogether and have a single editable div styled like an input?

Appreciate any responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This usually requires the use of `contenteditable="true"` ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content)), which is infamous for its horrible API and inconsistent behaviour across browsers.

So unless you have some special reason to write such a solution yourself, I can only advise you to build on an existing solution.

Comment: I agree with Linus, however if you still want to get something to work, this article might be helpful: https://medium.engineering/why-contenteditable-is-terrible-122d8a40e480 (don't get mislead by the title - it actually tells you how to fix the worst problems of contenteditable)